# hector_slam kinda running away

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

got a problem with `hector_slam` here. For about a minute or so it's working like a charm. I can drive around with my robot seeing its estimated pose being sufficiently precize. But after a while `hector_slam` tends to drift away. The matcher just appears to stop matching.

Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157556/hector_slam-kinda-running-away/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two likely causes for this:

1. The system uses a fixed size map behind the scenes, which should be of sufficient size for most scenarios. If your robot travels far, it could go beyond map borders.
2. You reach an area that leads to a scan matching failure due to not enough features in the environment, or the robot moves too fast.

There really should be no reason that leads to failures solely based on the time the system has been running.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-06**:
I've switched to AMCL now which works pretty well. Thanks anyway.